# Is there any Java SDK or library for interacting with Substrate nodes?

Tags: sdk, java, library

The links below have stopped supporting

- https://github.com/polkadot-java/api
- https://github.com/emeraldpay/polkaj

Is there a supported library that I can use?

Comment: Is it still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there are currently **no** supported Java client libraries listed here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/v3/integration/client-libraries

You can use Java with RPC.

Substrate exposes a number of RPC methods.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "rpc_methods"}' https://rpc.polkadot.io
```

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "state_getMetadata"}' https://rpc.polkadot.io
```

Reference:

- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-node-interaction
- https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/9969999/SWT5iLXH#da25ea74-d8b6-4a1b-a873-3d750c7840e7

Comment: Thanks, but the response of the rpc call is an encoded value, so I'm worried about how to handle it in Java.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/strategyobject/substrate-client-java is active, though incomplete.

Comment: I think it'd be good to use this as a reference later on. Thank you.